# jquery script works only on first input. Doesn't work on the same dynamically generated

Tags: jquery, forms, input

Hi guys have complex form and can't achieve some thing. Everything works on static but when i create more forms with the same inputs scripts doesn't work so let's start from the begining.

1. When i enter pad. kodas and par. kodas it automatically select from padalinys and pareigos by value. But when i push green button and generate another similar form script doesn't work. Ofcourse inputs similar but i need another values not the same which are in the static group.
2. When i choose in static form darbo pradzia it generates +3months in bandomasis laikotarpis, but the same problem when i generate new similar form with green plus. I need generate another date but script doesnt work again.
3. And last but not least i need when tableio nr., imone, miestas, padalinys, pareigos filled, jquery automatically select checkbox pagrindines how can I  achieve that?

Thanks

```js
$('#skaicius').val(2);
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#duomenys').submit(function(){
  $('#skaicius').val($('.fieldGroup').length*1+1);
 })
    //papildomu pareigu limitas
    var maxGroup = 10;
    //$('#skaicius').val(2);
    //papildomu pareigu pridejimas
    $(".prideti").click(function(){
        if($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < maxGroup){
            var fieldHTML = '<div class="row form-group fieldGroup">'+$(".fieldGroupCopy").html()+'</div>';
            $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
   
        }else{
            alert('Viršintas didžiausias papildomų pareigų skaičius.');
        }
    });
 
 
 $(document).on("change",".form-check-input",function(){
  var inputklase =$(this).attr("name");
  console.log(inputklase);
  $(this).closest("div").find("input."+inputklase).val($(this).is(":checked")?1:0);
   
 })    
 
    //papildomu pareigu salinimas
    $("body").on("click",".salinti",function(){ 
        $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
  
    });
 // limits pagrindines for one only checked
  $(document).on("change", ":checkbox[name=pagrindines1]", function() {
    var $ckb = $(":checkbox[name=pagrindines1]");
    var $checked = $ckb.filter(":checked");
    $ckb.not($checked).prop("disabled", $checked.length >= 1);
 });
 
 
// Generates start and end date
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('input[name=darbo_pradzia]').change(function(){
          let date = new Date($(this).val());
          let newDate = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+3));
          var day = ("0" + newDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
          var month = ("0" + (newDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
          var formatted = newDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
          $('input[name=bandomasis_laikotarpis]').val(formatted);
     });
});
 //select option from padalinys 
 (function($) {
  $('#test2').on('blur', function(e) {
    let inputVal = $(this).val();

    $('.padalinys option').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === inputVal) {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
      }
    })
  });
})(jQuery);
//select option from pareigos
(function($) {
  $('#test3').on('blur', function(e) {
    let inputVal = $(this).val();

    $('.pareigos option').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === inputVal) {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
      }
    })
  });
})(jQuery);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04b00d367c.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <div class="container">   
      <div class="row form-group fieldGroup">
      <h4>Darbuotojo pareigos</h4>
      <div style="position: relative; top: 8px; left: 10px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tbtn-print btn-sm btn-success prideti" title="[Pridėti pareigas]"><span class="fas fa-plus"></span></a></div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label class="text-black" for="kodas">Tabelio nr.</label>
                                <input type="text" id="tabelis" name="tabelio_numeris[]" class="form-control">
                            </div>
       <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label class="text-black" for="imone">Įmonė</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="imone[]" >
          @foreach ($imones as $imone)
                                        <option value="{{$imone->id}}">{{$imone->pavadinimas}}</option>
          @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label class="text-black" for="miestas">Miestas</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="miestas[]" >
                                    @foreach($miestai as $miestas)
                                        <option value="{{$miestas->pavadinimas}}">{{$miestas->pavadinimas}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label class="text-black" for="test2">Pad. kodas</label>
                                <input type="text" id="test2" name="padkodas[]" class="form-control">
                            </div>
       <div class="col-md-10">
                                <label class="text-black" for="padalinys">Padalinys</label>
                                <select class="form-control padalinys" name="padalinys[]" >
                                        <option value="1">test - 1</option>
          <option value="2">test - 2</option>
          <option value="3">test - 3</option>
          <option value="4">test - 4</option>
          <option value="5">test - 5</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label class="text-black" for="test2">Pareigu kodas</label>
                                <input type="text" id="test3" name="parkodas[]" class="form-control">
                            </div>
       <div class="col-md-10">
                                <label class="text-black" for="pareigos">Pareigos</label>
                                <select class="form-control pareigos" name="pareigos[]" >
                                        <option value="1">test - 1</option>
          <option value="2">test - 2</option>
          <option value="3">test - 3</option>
          <option value="4">test - 4</option>
          <option value="5">test - 5</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label class="text-black" for="dpradzia">Darbo pradžia</label>
                                <input type="date" id="darbo_pradzia" name="darbo_pradzia" class="form-control darbo_pradzia">
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label class="text-black" for="bandomasis_laikotarpis">Bandomasis laikotarpis</label>
                                <input type="date" id="bandomasis_laikotarpis" name="bandomasis_laikotarpis" class="form-control bandomasis_laikotarpis">
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label class="text-black" for="terminuota_sutartis">Terminuota sutartis</label>
                                <input type="date" id="terminuota_sutartis" name="terminuota_sutartis" class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label class="text-black" for="atldata">Atleidimo data</label>
                                <input type="date" id="atldata" name="atleidimo_data" class="form-control">
                            </div>

       
       <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="vadovas1" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top:10px;" class="form-check-input" value="1" >
        <input class="vadovas1" type="hidden" name="vadovas[]" value="0">
        <label class="form-check-label" style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top:5px;" id="vadovastxt">Vadovas</label>
                            </div>
       <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="checkbox" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top:10px;" class="form-check-input pagrindines" value="1" name="pagrindines1" >
        <input class="pagrindines1" type="hidden" name="pagrindines[]" value="0">
        <label class="form-check-label" style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top:5px;" id="pagrindinestxt">Pagrindinės (Generuoti barkodą pagal šią kortelę.)</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      <!-- Papildomos pareigos -->
      <div class="row form-group fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;" >
      <h4>Papildomos pareigos</h4>
      <div style="position: relative; top: 8px; left: 10px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tbtn-print btn-sm btn-danger salinti" title="[Šalinti]"><span class="fas fa-minus"></span></a></div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label class="text-black" for="kodas">Tabelio nr.</label>
                                <input type="text" id="tabelis" name="tabelio_numeris[]" class="form-control">
                            </div>
       <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label class="text-black" for="imone">Įmonė</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="imone[]" >
          @foreach ($imones as $imone)
                                        <option value="{{$imone->id}}">{{$imone->pavadinimas}}</option>
          @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label class="text-black" for="miestas">Miestas</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="miestas[]" >
                                    @foreach($miestai as $miestas)
                                        <option value="{{$miestas->pavadinimas}}">{{$miestas->pavadinimas}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label class="text-black" for="test2">Pad. kodas</label>
                                <input type="text" id="test2" name="padkodas[]" class="form-control">
                            </div>
       <div class="col-md-10">
                                <label class="text-black" for="padalinys">Padalinys</label>
                                <select class="form-control padalinys" name="padalinys[]" >
                                        <option value="1">test - 1</option>
          <option value="2">test - 2</option>
          <option value="3">test - 3</option>
          <option value="4">test - 4</option>
          <option value="5">test - 5</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label class="text-black" for="test2">Pareigu kodas</label>
                                <input type="text" id="test2" name="parkodas[]" class="form-control">
                            </div>
       <div class="col-md-10">
                                <label class="text-black" for="pareigos">Pareigos</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="pareigos[]" >
                                        <option value="1">test - 1</option>
          <option value="2">test - 2</option>
          <option value="3">test - 3</option>
          <option value="4">test - 4</option>
          <option value="5">test - 5</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label class="text-black" for="dpradzia">Darbo pradžia</label>
                                <input type="date" id="darbo_pradzia" name="darbo_pradzia" class="form-control darbo_pradzia">
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label class="text-black" for="bandomasis_laikotarpis">Bandomasis laikotarpis</label>
                                <input type="date" id="bandomasis_laikotarpis" name="bandomasis_laikotarpis" class="form-control bandomasis_laikotarpis">
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label class="text-black" for="terminuota_sutartis">Terminuota sutartis</label>
                                <input type="date" id="terminuota_sutartis" name="terminuota_sutartis" class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label class="text-black" for="atldata">Atleidimo data</label>
                                <input type="date" id="atldata" name="atleidimo_data" class="form-control">
                            </div>

       
       <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="vadovas1" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top:10px;" class="form-check-input" value="1" >
        <input class="vadovas1" type="hidden" name="vadovas[]" value="0">
        <label class="form-check-label" style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top:5px;" id="vadovastxt">Vadovas</label>
                            </div>
       <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="checkbox" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top:10px;" class="form-check-input pagrindines" name="pagrindines1" >
        <input class="pagrindines1" type="hidden" name="pagrindines[]" value="0">
        <label class="form-check-label" style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top:5px;" id="pagrindinestxt">Pagrindinės (Generuoti barkodą pagal šią kortelę.)</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      <!-- Papildomos pareigos pabaiga -->
      
   </div>
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want some of the input values to carry over in the newly generated forms when you click the green button, or what do you mean specifically?

Comment: Not that. I want that on generated inputs script works to, but wit new values not old one.
For example if i write pad.kodas and script select padalinys, but when i push plus i need the same action but different values and now script works only for first form and on generated it doesn't work at all. Generated inputs has the same class and input name.

Comment: Okay so 1 thing. Why are you using multiple `document.ready` blocks? Also, for some functions you are correctly using event handlers, which will be able to deal with dynamically added content, while in other places, you are using DOM specific events, which will not be able to deal with dynamically added content since it does not care about what happens once the DOM has been loaded ONCE.

Comment: `$(document).on("change",".form-check-input",function(){ //code });` will be able to deal with dynamically added content.  `$('input[name=darbo_pradzia]').change(function(){ //code });` will only care about content that has already been created when the DOM was loaded (i.e. non dynamically added HTML). I'm guessing you did some trial and error with this and decided to go with the `document.ready` block, which indeed does make it work for the static instances of the HTML, but not the dynamicly added content.